# Calling function in react native outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**My requirement**

I am calling my function placed outside of the component and view in react native, but it throws errors saying the _this.myfunction is undefined. Its clearly not getting the reference for the function. Is it possible to achieve such feature in react native.

```
class  App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

   render () {
       return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button onPress={() => this.Myfunction()} style={styles.Button} title="Button"/>                            
            </View>
       );
     }
 }       

Myfunction () {
  alert('clicked');          
}
```

Comment: `this` refers to the class ( App ). But your function is declared ( add `function` keyword ) outside the class ( intentionally ) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've defined the function outside of the class, you don't need to refer it by `this`. You can simply write `onPress={() => Myfunction()}` or `onPress={Myfunction}`

Also your function's syntax is wrong, add the `function` keyword before it

```
function Myfunction () {
  alert('clicked');          
}
```